# How to make an object change random color

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to get this ornaments on the tree to change color, it can be with a timer or some other method but I've been struggling as i'm quite new at this. I have them set as an initial color and added a random color generator but don't know what my next step would be.

```
int ornament = (int)(5 * this.scale);
Oval blueornament = new Oval(this.x - (int)(10 * this.scale), this.y - (int)(10 * this.scale), 2 * ornament, 2 * ornament, Color.blue, true);
Oval yellowornament = new Oval(this.x + (int)(10 * this.scale), this.y - (int)(20 * this.scale), 2 * ornament, 2 * ornament, Color.yellow, true);
Oval redornament = new Oval(this.x + (int)(15 * this.scale), this.y + (int)(5 * this.scale), 2 * ornament, 2 * ornament, Color.red, true);

this.window.add(trunk);
this.window.add(foliage);
this.window.add(foliage2);
this.window.add(foliage3);
this.window.add(blueornament);
this.window.add(yellowornament);
this.window.add(redornament);

public void flashOrnaments() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    float r = rand.nextFloat();
    float g = rand.nextFloat();
    float b = rand.nextFloat();
    Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: What is the base class of your `Oval` objects?

Comment: what is wrong with your code so far?

Comment: add this.window.add(new Oval(this.x + (int)(15 * this.scale), this.y + (int)(5 * this.scale), 2 * ornament, 2 * ornament, randomColor, true); at the end of the method flashOrnaments

Comment: @NicolasFilotto you don't want to keep adding new shapes, that's going to be really inefficient.

Comment: @JamesTaylor frankly speaking I don't get what the OP expects here

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto I apologize for anything unclear, it's supposed to be an animated Christmas tree with the ovals changing colors, as if they were lights. I have the image built, but attempting to get the ovals changing colors is being difficult. The Oval is from a graphics library from the school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I've done this (3 years), but I think this should give you the general gist about how to approach this problem.

If you want to change the color of an existing shape, I think you can alter the graphics object when drawing. I tried to search the Java standard library for an `Oval`, [but there isn't one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html), so it looks like you made this on your own.

So I would alter the `Oval` class to look like this:

```
public class Oval extends JPanel {
    private Color color;

    public Oval(Color color) {
        this.color = color.
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(this.color);
    }

    public void changeColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

So then calling something like `blueornament.setColor(Color.red)` should work.

Now, if you want to animate the color which I'm assuming is what you are after because you are talking about a timer, you can just keep programmatically setting the color, in 'steps' until you reach the desired color (untested, just to give the general idea):

```
Color oldColor = Oval.color;
Color newColor = randomColor();

// Calculate the difference between the old and new color
int rdiff = (oldColor.getRed() - newColor.getRed()) / 20;
int gdiff = (oldColor.getGreen() - newColor.getGreen()) / 20;
int bdiff = (oldColor.getBlue() - newColor.getBlue()) / 20;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // Programmatically setup timers, because Thread.sleep() doesn't work here
    int delay = 10 * i;
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // Get the current color and step one further
            int red = Oval.color.getRed() + rdiff;
            int green = Oval.color.getGreen() + gdiff;
            int blue = Oval.color.getBlue() + bdiff;

            oval.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
        }
    };
    new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
}
```

Hope this sets you on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `window` is an `java.awt.Window` and your `Oval` is an instance of `java.awt.Component` and you're trying to change the colors of your `Oval` objects. Then for `flashingOrnaments` you need to loop over all `Oval` objects you added to your `window` and set the Background/Foreground to your `randomColor`, eg:

```
for (Component component : this.window.getComponents()) {
    if (component instanceof Oval) {
        component.setBackground(randomColor);
    }
}
```